# Next.js-Passport How to get user data after succesfull login?[client side routing]

Tags: express, passport.js, next.js

I am trying to access user data after succesfull login and also from every component.This is how i login the user:

```
    router.post("/user/login",(req,res,next)=>{

    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user)) // here i got user data
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!user) { return res.send("fail"); }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
          if (err) { return next(err); }
          return res.send("success") // when client gets success message,it will do Router.push("/dashboard")

        });
      })(req, res, next);


})
```

Server configuration:

```
  server.use(cookieParser())
  server.use(bodyParser.json())
  server.use(passport.initialize());
  server.use(session({
  secret: 'jumpingdonger',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie : { secure : false, maxAge : (4 * 60 * 60 * 1000) }, // 4 hours
}))
//Passport Middleware
server.use(passport.initialize())
server.use(passport.session())
```

DashBoard page:

```
import Header from '../components/Header'

import Layout from '../components/MyLayout.js'
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Router from 'next/router'


export default class DashBoard extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);



    this.state = { 


    };
  }  
  componentWillMount(){
console.log(this.props)

  }


  logout =()=>{
    axios.get('/api/user/logout').then((result)=>{

            if(result.data=="success"){
                Router.push("/")
            }

    })



  }
  render(){
    if(this.props.userData == undefined){
      return(
        <Layout>
       <p>First you must login!</p>

    </Layout>
      )
    }else{
      return(

        <Layout>
               <p>Welcome to your dashboard {this.props.userData.userName}</p>

               <a onClick={this.logout}>logout</a>
            </Layout>


        )

    }





  }




}
DashBoard.getInitialProps = async function(context) {

  if(context.req !=undefined){ // which means that we are from server
    return { 
      userData:context.req.user


       };
  }else{
    return{}
  }

  }
```

So after succesfull login,i am redirected to dashboard page.Now in dashboard component i am trying to get userdata on `getInitialProps`.The problem is since i am redirected by client using `Router.push()`,i cant get data on `getInitialProps` unless i dont refresh the page from browser.If i refresh,`context.req.user` is populated by user data.So how do i access userdata with client side routing from dashboard page and also every other page ? What i couldnt understand is, is this puting user data into a cookie which i can access from client or is this a server side session ?
thanks

EDIT:
I solved the problem by transfering userData from server to client on succesfull login and seting a cookie in client side.I wonder is this a correct solution in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

If user is logged in. `passport` will create `user` object in req for every request in `express`.

```
if (req.user) {
  // logged in
} else {
  // not logged in
}
```

In `next.js` when you use `getInitialProps` you have access to server with `context.req`.
like this:

```
static async getInitialProps({req}){
 if(req){
   // called on server
   // here you can check for that user object
 } else {
  // called on client
 }
```

}

However this cod will work if you have a SSR request in your `next.js` app (refresh page or put url and press enter).

You authenticate in server, so there is no way to find out if you have the same in front-end, Unless you use the token and verify the token in front-end as well.
Have a look at [Express session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) which will help you with cookies.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.Finally i have managed to access userdata inside context.req.user.But as you said,if client side routing is used i couldnt access that.So still i am looking for a way to access user data on client side routing

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a redux store to solve this problem. If you have set up your redux store, you need to hydrate that into your redux store. 
In your _app.js file add this code. Your pages can connect to the store.

```
  componentDidMount () {
   const { pageProps: { user }, reduxStore: { dispatch } } = this.props
   if (user) {
     dispatch({
       type: FETCH_USER,
       payload: user
    })
   }
  }
```